For Baremetal Raspberry Pi Zero 2W, how can I use GPIO pins?
I did find the Megathread on RPI forums
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=72260
and many tutorials but I can't seem to make them work
I wanted to follow this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZkK0xMpgPQ4.
I understand the Assembly code, but do not understand the compiling, how do I compile such files to kernel7.img files?
Would be nice if someone could redirect me to some tutorial of sorts, Specifically for Zero 2W.
Also I am using the arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler on ubuntu/debian. I also tried aarch64-elf toolchain, but still the same error.
As to what I tried, In C I tried
void main(void){
    int *gpio;
    gpio = (int*)0x3f200000;
    int *PIN32_OUTPUT_SELECT; 
    PIN32_OUTPUT_SELECT = (int*)0x3f200008; // OUTPUT SELECT for pin 21
    int *toodle;
    toodle = (int*)0x3f20001C; // 
    *PIN32_OUTPUT_SELECT = 9;
    while (1){
        *toodle = 0x00200000;
    }
}

and compiling and making the .img file as fllowing

arm-none-eabi-gcc -Iinclude -MMD -MP -specs=nosys.specs -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -nostdinc -nostdlib -nostartfiles -c src/main.c -o obj/main.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -nostdlib main.o -T link.ld -o kernel7.elf >> About the link.ld down at bottom
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary kernel7.elf kernel7.img

Link.ld:

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x80000;
    .text : { KEEP(*(.text.boot)) *(.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t*) }
    .rodata : { *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r*) }
    PROVIDE(_data = .);
    .data : { *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d*) }
    .bss (NOLOAD) : {
        . = ALIGN(16);
        __bss_start = .;
        *(.bss .bss.*)
        *(COMMON)
        __bss_end = .;
    }
    _end = .;

   /DISCARD/ : { *(.comment) *(.gnu*) *(.note*) *(.eh_frame*) }
}
__bss_size = (__bss_end - __bss_start)>>3;


